# SonarQube for MSBuild - End Analysis failure

Tags: sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarqube-scan

Have spent more that 20 hours on this issue, but could not resolve.

Requirement - SONARQube integration with MSBuild in visual studio online.

Steps followed -

To Setup SONARQube-5.6

1. A Windows server VM on Azure with SQL Server 2012.
2. Followed the following steps provided in the below two links

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server
http://donovanbrown.com/post/2015/06/17/how-to-setup-a-sonarqube-server-in-azure

3. Using SQL Server with SQL Authentication.
4. Sonar is running as windows service.
5. JDK 8, JRE 8 installed

**Problem 1 -** SONARQube is accesible with the following url http://abc.cloudapp.net:9000 on the server itself. Outside the server via internet it is not accessible.

Integration of SONARQube in MSBuild

Followed the steps provided in the below link
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis/

**Problem 2 -**

When i queue the build, the Begin Analysis step is successfully executed to fetch the SONAR profile. After the solution build step, when the End Analysis step is executed, this step fails with the following error.

```
2016-07-20T11:47:55.0719979Z 11:47:54.868 INFO  - Analysis report generated in 218ms, dir size=1 MB
2016-07-20T11:47:55.1813633Z 11:47:54.993 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 125ms, zip size=593 KB
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z Total time: 25.270s
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z Final Memory: 12M/419M
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]Caused by: org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 500 on http://nstudio36db.cloudapp.net:9000/api/ce/submit?projectKey=nstudio36&projectName=nstudio36POC
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:34)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.failIfUnauthorized(BatchWsClient.java:99)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchWsClient.call(BatchWsClient.java:69)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.upload(ReportPublisher.java:172)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.report.ReportPublisher.execute(ReportPublisher.java:127)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.publishReportJob(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:64)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.phases.PublishPhaseExecutor.executeOnRoot(PublishPhaseExecutor.java:51)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:86)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:79)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]... 9 more
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]ERROR:
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Runner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z ##[error]The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9512068Z 11:47:55.873  Creating a summary markdown file...
2016-07-20T11:47:55.9668295Z ##[error]Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1
2016-07-20T11:47:56.0157824Z ##[error]System.Exception: Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1
2016-07-20T11:47:56.0157824Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.PowerShell.InvokeBatchScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2016-07-20T11:47:56.0157824Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
2016-07-20T11:47:56.0626590Z ##[debug]Calling InvokeGetRestMethod "/api/server/version" 
2016-07-20T11:47:56.0939103Z ##[debug]GET http://nstudio36db.cloudapp.net:9000/api/server/version with 0-byte payload
2016-07-20T11:47:56.2411799Z ##[debug]received 3-byte response of content type text/html;charset=utf-8
2016-07-20T11:47:56.2935352Z Waiting on the SonarQube server to finish processing in order to determine the quality gate status.
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version is lower than 5.3 - for more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407 ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Cannot determine if the analysis has finished. Possible cause: your SonarQube server version is lower than 5.3 - for more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722407
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]   at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.PowerShellHandler.Execute(ITaskContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 timeoutInMinutes)
2016-07-20T11:47:56.3327387Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.RunTask(ITaskContext context, TaskWrapper task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
```

**Surprise Element**

1. The End analysis step was executing and the report was being uploaded initially. After 2-3 days, i had shut down the VM. One day i started it again, and things stopped working.
2. The `sonar.properties` file in config where the sonar is installed, nothing has been changed after extracting it from the downloaded zip version. If i make the changes as asked in the Installation Guide of SONARQube website 
   http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server
   the windows service Sonar Qube does not even run, it starts and stops with some error logged.

I am also attaching the logs of SONARQube for more clarification

Contents of Sonar.log

```
SonarQube removed.
CreateService failed - The specified service has been marked for deletion. (0x430)
Starting the SonarQube service...
Unable to start the service - The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it. (0x422)
SonarQube installed.
Starting the SonarQube service...
--> Wrapper Started as Service
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016.07.20 11:42:19 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\SonarCubeNStudio\temp
2016.07.20 11:42:19 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\SonarCubeNStudio\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\SonarCubeNStudio\temp\sq-process8674696029876155294properties
2016.07.20 11:42:21 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2016.07.20 11:42:21 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2016.07.20 11:42:21 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469014939182] version[1.7.5], pid[5080], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2016.07.20 11:42:21 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469014939182] initializing ...
2016.07.20 11:42:21 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1469014939182] loaded [], sites []
SonarQube started.
2016.07.20 11:42:23 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1469014939182] using [1] data paths, mounts [[(C:)]], net usable_space [84.9gb], net total_space [126.9gb], types [NTFS]
2016.07.20 11:42:26 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2016.07.20 11:42:29 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469014939182] initialized
2016.07.20 11:42:29 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469014939182] starting ...
2016.07.20 11:42:29 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1469014939182] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2016.07.20 11:42:29 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1469014939182] sonarqube/tJjpPHT5QwKQ0DICqUP99w
2016.07.20 11:42:33 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1469014939182] new_master [sonar-1469014939182][tJjpPHT5QwKQ0DICqUP99w][nstudio36db][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1469014939182}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2016.07.20 11:42:33 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1469014939182] started
2016.07.20 11:42:33 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1469014939182] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2016.07.20 11:42:33 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2016.07.20 11:42:33 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\SonarCubeNStudio\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;C:\SonarCubeNStudio\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer C:\SonarCubeNStudio\temp\sq-process3740500123831706040properties
2016.07.20 11:42:35 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2016.07.20 11:42:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: C:\SonarCubeNStudio\web
2016.07.20 11:42:37 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.07.20 11:42:37 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2016.07.20 11:42:39 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6 / 074f3d1169f9688d15af4aff67e7e672cbeed782
2016.07.20 11:42:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Starting embedded database on port 9092 with url jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.07.20 11:42:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.EmbeddedDatabase] Embedded database started. Data stored in: C:\SonarCubeNStudio\data
2016.07.20 11:42:40 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.07.20 11:42:41 WARN  web[o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2016.07.20 11:42:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: C:\SonarCubeNStudio
2016.07.20 11:42:45 INFO  web[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1469014939182] loaded [], sites []
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin C# [csharp] installed
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin Java [java] installed
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin JavaScript [javascript] installed
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin Git [scmgit] installed
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Plugin SVN [scmsvn] installed
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin C# / 5.0 / 17ddb09047940791828dcb70c9e225f006ab11aa
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Git / 1.2 / a713dd64daf8719ba4e7f551f9a1966c62690c17
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Java / 3.13.1 / cf0f0c950ba3e83a87c7fe11c6ff7e63f4864bd9
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin JavaScript / 2.11 / a9b1afa9ceef7079811779d9efc5f8026acb1400
2016.07.20 11:42:48 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SVN / 1.3 / aff503d48bc77b07c2b62abf93249d0a20bd355c
2016.07.20 11:42:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Create database
2016.07.20 11:42:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer] Deploying Ruby on Rails applications
2016.07.20 11:42:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2016.07.20 11:42:54 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index tests
2016.07.20 11:42:55 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [tests] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[0], mappings []
2016.07.20 11:42:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type tests/test
2016.07.20 11:42:58 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [tests] create_mapping [test]
2016.07.20 11:42:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index activities
2016.07.20 11:42:58 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [activities] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[0], mappings []
2016.07.20 11:42:59 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type activities/activity
2016.07.20 11:42:59 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [activities] create_mapping [activity]
2016.07.20 11:42:59 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index rules
2016.07.20 11:42:59 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [rules] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[0], mappings []
2016.07.20 11:43:00 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type rules/activeRule
2016.07.20 11:43:00 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [rules] create_mapping [activeRule]
2016.07.20 11:43:00 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type rules/rule
2016.07.20 11:43:00 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [rules] create_mapping [rule]
2016.07.20 11:43:00 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index issues
2016.07.20 11:43:00 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [issues] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[0], mappings []
2016.07.20 11:43:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type issues/authorization
2016.07.20 11:43:01 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [issues] create_mapping [authorization]
2016.07.20 11:43:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type issues/issue
2016.07.20 11:43:01 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [issues] create_mapping [issue]
2016.07.20 11:43:01 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index users
2016.07.20 11:43:01 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [users] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[0], mappings []
2016.07.20 11:43:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type users/user
2016.07.20 11:43:02 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [users] create_mapping [user]
2016.07.20 11:43:02 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create index views
2016.07.20 11:43:02 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [views] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[0], mappings []
2016.07.20 11:43:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexCreator] Create type views/view
2016.07.20 11:43:03 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [views] create_mapping [view]
2016.07.20 11:43:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2016.07.20 11:43:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2016.07.20 11:43:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2016.07.20 11:43:20 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2016.07.20 11:43:22 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register profile {lang=cs, name=Sonar way}
2016.07.20 11:43:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Set default cs profile: Sonar way
2016.07.20 11:43:24 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register profile {lang=java, name=Sonar way}
2016.07.20 11:43:27 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Set default java profile: Sonar way
2016.07.20 11:43:27 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register profile {lang=js, name=Sonar way}
2016.07.20 11:43:28 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register profile {lang=js, name=Sonar Security Way}
2016.07.20 11:43:28 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Set default js profile: Sonar way
2016.07.20 11:43:31 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
2016.07.20 11:43:31 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filter: Projects
2016.07.20 11:43:31 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filter: My favourites
2016.07.20 11:43:31 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
2016.07.20 11:43:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboard: Custom
2016.07.20 11:43:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboard: Home
2016.07.20 11:43:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2016.07.20 11:43:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2016.07.20 11:43:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameIssueWidgets] Replacing issue related widgets with issue filter widgets
2016.07.20 11:43:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index activities
2016.07.20 11:43:34 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [activities] update_mapping [activity] (dynamic)
2016.07.20 11:43:34 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [activities] update_mapping [activity] (dynamic)
2016.07.20 11:43:35 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [activities] update_mapping [activity] (dynamic)
2016.07.20 11:43:35 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.metadata]  [sonar-1469014939182] [activities] update_mapping [activity] (dynamic)
2016.07.20 11:43:35 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
2016.07.20 11:43:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
2016.07.20 11:43:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index users
2016.07.20 11:43:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index views
2016.07.20 11:43:37 INFO  web[jruby.rack] jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_101-b13 [Windows Server 2012 R2-amd64]
2016.07.20 11:43:37 INFO  web[jruby.rack] using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
2016.07.20 11:44:09 INFO  web[jruby.rack] keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
2016.07.20 11:44:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@1653ae93 [pattern=/sessions/init/*]
2016.07.20 11:44:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@363262a [pattern=/oauth2/callback/*]
2016.07.20 11:44:09 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-0.0.0.0-9000"]
2016.07.20 11:44:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2016.07.20 11:44:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000
2016.07.20 11:44:10 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2016.07.20 11:44:10 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[ce]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\SonarCubeNStudio\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/server/*;./lib/ce/*;C:\SonarCubeNStudio\lib\jdbc\h2\h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer C:\SonarCubeNStudio\temp\sq-process5870977745631384763properties
2016.07.20 11:44:12 INFO  ce[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting ce
2016.07.20 11:44:12 INFO  ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine starting up...
2016.07.20 11:44:13 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6 / 074f3d1169f9688d15af4aff67e7e672cbeed782
2016.07.20 11:44:13 INFO  ce[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar
2016.07.20 11:44:13 WARN  ce[o.s.d.DatabaseChecker] H2 database should be used for evaluation purpose only
2016.07.20 11:44:17 INFO  ce[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem] SonarQube home: C:\SonarCubeNStudio
2016.07.20 11:44:18 INFO  ce[o.e.plugins] [sonar-1469014939182] loaded [], sites []
2016.07.20 11:44:21 INFO  ce[o.s.c.c.CePluginRepository] Load plugins
2016.07.20 11:44:26 INFO  ce[o.s.s.c.q.PurgeCeActivities] Delete the Compute Engine tasks created before Fri Jan 22 11:44:26 UTC 2016
2016.07.20 11:44:26 INFO  ce[o.s.ce.app.CeServer] Compute Engine is up
2016.07.20 11:44:27 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[ce] is up
2016.07.20 11:47:54 ERROR web[rails] /!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Wed Jul 20 11:47:54 UTC 2016
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  No such file or directory - C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Local/Temp
    org/jruby/RubyFile.java:842:in `stat'
    jar:file:/C:/SonarCubeNStudio/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:33:in `tmpdir'
    org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    jar:file:/C:/SonarCubeNStudio/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:30:in `tmpdir'
    jar:file:/C:/SonarCubeNStudio/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:109:in `tmpdir'
    jar:file:/C:/SonarCubeNStudio/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/tmpdir.rb:141:in `create'
    org/jruby/ext/tempfile/Tempfile.java:88:in `initialize'
    org/jruby/RubyIO.java:852:in `new'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/utils.rb:559:in `parse_multipart'
    org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1519:in `loop'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/utils.rb:537:in `parse_multipart'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/request.rb:268:in `parse_multipart'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/request.rb:146:in `POST'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:15:in `call'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    file:/C:/SonarCubeNStudio/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rack-1.1.6/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:58:in `call'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    C:/SonarCubeNStudio/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
    file:/C:/SonarCubeNStudio/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
    file:/C:/SonarCubeNStudio/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
    file:/C:/SonarCubeNStudio/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Comment: Your log seems to indicate that the analysis report is submitted to the server. Do you see it on the server? Is it successfully processed on the server? Is there anything relevant/interesting in the server log? (Pls respond with a question [edit], not a comment)

Answer (score 3):

The error on the server side (occurring during a call to *api/ce/submit* on the client side) matches pretty well with known bug [SONAR-7896](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7896) - *Analysis fails if SonarQube runs as a Windows Service* (which is your case here).

Workarounds are listed in the ticket:

> - in `<sonar_install_dir>/conf/wrapper.conf` , add `set.TMPDIR=../../temp`
> - OR in the Windows Services Administrative Tool, edit the SonarQube service properties, change 'Log on' from 'Local System account' to
>     'This account' (providing your local admin username/password)
> - OR manually run SonarQube from command line

Comment: You were correct. Sonar being hosted as windows service was causing the problem. 1. I am hosting as a web server now. It works. 2. Tried changing the logon to this account with admin user name and password of the system. The service did not event start, stating logon failure. Did not try the other two solutions. Will try in some free time. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @Ravi The first workaround should work nonetheless, give a try to that one. Also, do [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer if it solved your question.

Comment: Accepted it :). Apologies for missing it. You can also add hosting Sonar as a web server in the same. Just a suggestion though